# Can I use the Alpha is Transparency setting for an image loaded at runtime from outside the project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a system in my Unity project (2017.2.0f3) wherein a class will grab images from a specific folder outside of the project on the local system for use with a character skin. I need these textures to exist outside the project because I want to allow players to add additional content to the game post-build.

My method for doing this is use of the WWW class, specifically by creating a Texture2D and loading an image into memory with WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture(). It is working just fine this way, no problems with that part. When I display these images in the UI they look really bad. If I manually add the same image to the project and check "Alpha is Transparency" they look just fine. I want to be able to apply that setting to the images as I load them into memory, but I can't figure out how.

I know that the setting dilates the color of the image, as is described here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TextureTypes.html

I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow do this on the fly programmatically. Has anyone tried this before? I'd imagine that the WWW class isn't the best method to be doing this with, but I can't find any info about other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Facing up this problem I've discovered the following solution:

```
public static void AlphaIsTransparency(this Texture2D texture)
{
    Color[] pixels = texture.GetPixels();
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
    {
        if(Mathf.Approximately(pixels[i].a, 0)) 
            pixels[i] = new Color();
    }
    texture.SetPixels(pixels);
    texture.Apply();
}
```

Usage:

```
var texture = new Texture2D(
    512, 512,
    TextureFormat.RGBA32, false
);
texture.LoadImage(File.ReadAllBytes(fileFullName));
texture.AlphaIsTransparency();
```

This extension method simulates the behavior of Unity TextureImporter with alphaIsTransparency=true, according to https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureImporterSettings-alphaIsTransparency.html. I cannot guarantee 100% the same result, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this method :
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html

So you can at first create a texture in the format you would like and then using this method to load the image from a byte array.

You can get all the bytes of the file from System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

Comment: It isn't actually a formatting issue at all. WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture() will load png files as ARGB32 which is what I need. I need my images to be color dilated on the fly.